# Error message while cut string in windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am writing Windows batch script and the following line always gave error message but it's working normally if ran direct from command line.

```
IF %p_monitorName%=="workflow_failed" (
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=," %a in ("%p_monitorStatus: by =.%") do for /F "tokens=3 delims=:" %b in ("%a: by =.%") do for /F "tokens=1 delims= " %c in ("%b by =.%") do echo %c >> %scriptdir%\..\logs\SIS2OVOOutput.txt
)
```

here's the error message:

```
9480 ERROR: , Unknown error (255) end perfex
```

Comment: there a few issues with your script but to help you I first need it's purpose and intended logic

Comment: why you are trying 3 times to replace `by` with `.` ?

Comment: Are you using `%%` instead of `%` within you batch file?

Comment: I am trying to cut string, and in command line this works, I am shell script and it's 1st time for me to script in windows, I am using %c instead of %%c for example, will edit this.

Answer (score 0):

Within a bat file you have to use `%%` instead of `%` in the for loop:

```
IF %p_monitorName%=="workflow_failed" (
    for /F "tokens=1 delims=," %%a in ("%p_monitorStatus: by =.%") do for /F "tokens=3 delims=:" %%b in ("%%a: by =.%") do for /F "tokens=1 delims= " %%c in ("%%b by =.%") do echo %%c >> %scriptdir%\..\logs\SIS2OVOOutput.txt
)
```

That should be it.

Comment: How to use %%c somewhere else in script ?